# Method or data member not found .txtRowNumber

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

On Compile I get a

> "Method or data member not found"

I have tried (in vain) to find where this needs to be established in my VBA code (running on the back of an Excel spreadsheet) but been unsuccessful so far so I hope you can point me in the right direction.  The error is a missing .txtRowNumber that gets highlighted.  Here is a sample of the code where it flags.

```
Sub Reset()

Dim iRow As Long

iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Database").Range("A:A")) ' identifying the last row

With frmForm

    .txtRowNumber.Value = ""
    
    
    .cmbCategory.Clear
```

Hope you can be of assistance please as I am very new to all this and got quite deep into it.

Thank you

Paul

Tried to research it against other websites and nothing that I could find could help point me in the direction of where to find it.

Comment: Do you have a form named `frmForm` and a textbox on that form called `txtRowNumber` ?

Comment: Yes I do ... Contains the follow:

Me.txtRowNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 0), _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), 0)

Comment: Since you put the code in the worksheet, you cannot use `Me` to refer to the form, so use `frmForm.lstDatabase` instead of `Me.lstDatabase` in both places in the code you added in your comment. - this assumes you also have `ListBox` on your form called `lstDatabase`.

Comment: Thank you I will try without the Me in there - no idea how that got in there!

Comment: That got rid of that problem and now I am hung up on an Invalid or unqualified reference.

If .EnableEvents = False Then Exit Sub

Comment: Maybe you put it in the wrong place? It's hard to know since that code is not in your question.

Comment: Do you understand how `With` blocks work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: Hi braX

So what I am trying to do is follow a YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P53T6oxgUVA for create a database from an existing spreadsheet (17 columns 804 rows) with an input form.

I have aborted where I was at and started over again now for the 5th time and am just coming now to the end of the first video (hyperlink above) and I realize that I cannot even get the initial macro to work without it falling over!

Is there a way I can share the file with you please?

Comment: Any way - basically when I try to execute the Macro it now fails on the sub routine to show the form frmForm.Show command line in the Module element.  I tried to attach the code I have in the Module but it is too long (by 6311 characters!) for this dialogue box